# Почему приставки под, над не меняют конечную согласную

Tags: словообразование

Почему в Русском языке приставки пред, над, под не меняют конечную согласную перед глухими согласными в корне?

Comment: @AMK1112, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: А почему они должны менять? В правилах о том ничего нет - потому и "не меняют". Тут еще можно спрашивать (да и то не очень серьезно), почему только из/воз/рас и подобные ***меняют***., вернее, ***почему именно для них придумано специальное правило***, еще вернее: ***о чем думали авторы этой орфографической нормы.*** Вот на последний вопрос я бы еще рискнул ответить содержательно.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно морфологическому принципу русского письма, все морфемы (приставки, корни, суффиксы,окончания) стремятся сохранить свой буквенный состав, поэтому фонетическое чередование Д/Т перед глухим согласным корня не отражается на письме.

Нарушают закон приставки на З/С, которые пишутся по слуху (фонетическое письмо), но у них своя история.

Comment: "Нарушают закон приставки на З/С, которые пишутся по слуху (фонетическое письмо), но у них своя история."

Напротив, сам закон грубо прошёлся по правописанию и, вводя фонетическое письмо, не пощадил тех, для кого приставка "бес" неприемлема. Что интересно, смысл почти всех слов с этой приставкой имеет оценку негативную.

Comment: Причем не все приставки на з/с нарушают это правило - приставка "с" всегда пишется как "с", хотя перед звонкими произносится как "з", например "сделал".

Answer (score 1):

Vera ответила совершенно верно. Остаётся объяснить, почему приставки на -з/-с пишутся по фонетическому принципу.

Причина кроется в глубокой истории русского языка. Дело в том, что эти приставки, в отличие от всех остальных, никогда не были предлогами, то есть самостоятельными словами, и потому между конечным звуком такой приставки и начальным звуком следующей части слова не было, условно говоря, никакого "зазора", никакой паузы, вследствие чего ассимиляция (т. е. фонетическое приспособление) последнего согласного приставки к первому согласному корня происходила регулярно и с самых древнейших времен.

Впрочем, и правописание приставок на з\с не полностью фонетично. Скажем, в слове безжалостный на месте орфографического з на самом деле слышится \ж\, а в словебесшумный на конце приставки звучит отнюдь не \с\, а \ш. Иначе говоря, при написании такого рода приставок орфография отражает лишь одну из особенностей их звучания: звонкость или глухость, определяющуюся следующим звуком. Да и то, строго говоря, не столько звуком, сколько … буквой. Обратите внимание: слово безвкусный пишется с орфографическим вариантом без-, хотя на месте орфографического з в действительности произносится глухой звук \с\ (так как последующее в оглушается перед звуком\к). Но реальное звучание затмевается в нашем сознании силой зрительного воздействия буквы.

В сугубо методических целях один из исследователей современного русского письма предлагает использовать следующий забавный мини-диалог, где объединены все десять согласных букв, перед которыми конечный согласный перечисленных выше приставок всегда обозначается буквой с: "- Степка, хочешь щец? - Фи!" [Мейеров В.Ф. Современное русское письмо: Обозначение звуков в слабых позициях: Учебное пособие. Иркутск, изд-во Иркутского университета. 1995. С. 87].

Comment: Людмила, так эта фраза - просто список из глухих согласных в русском. Использовать его для для столь узкой цели как-то и не к лицу...

Comment: .."эти приставки, в отличие от всех остальных, никогда не были предлогами".. Удивительное встречается порой в глубокой истории русского языка.

Comment: ."эти приставки, в отличие от всех остальных, никогда не были предлогами" - Кхм... **Без** исключений?